# Get indexPath of UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom CollectionViewCell class, I have then generated an amount of these inside of a CollectionView. I have then also added a modal segue when the ViewCells are touched. How would I get the id (or index path) of which cell was pressed when the modal segue is activated.

I saw on here that someone suggested I add into the ViewCell.m file the method

```
-(void)collectionView: (UICollectionView*)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
//get indexpath variable in here
}
```

But this method does not seem to be getting called. Can anyone help me with what method would need to be get called for when a CollectionViewCell has a modal segue to get the indexpath.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If the views you have added to your cells are handling the touch by firing a segue, then the `collectionViewCell` never has a chance to receive the touch.

If you want the `collectionViewCell` to handle it, make the subviews of your cell purely decorative by disabling their behavior to fire the segue. (for example, if they are buttons and "`touchUpInside`" fires the segue, then change them into views with no touch handling at all.).

Then the touch will be passed up through the view hierarchy until the `CollectionViewCell` handles it, which it does with the `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` method.

Answer (score 0):

The method is a callback of the delegate class of the collection view object:

```
-(void)collectionView: (UICollectionView*)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath*)indexPath
```

So you should implement on the .m file of the delegate class of you collection view.